# How to increase the shown results from mobiscroll

Tags: html, css, mobiscroll

i'm just working on an application which has a inline-scroller included. It works fine but i want to increase the results mobiscroll gives out.

I have a DB-Request which fills my Mobiscroll with select values but it only show me the first 2 results from my DB.

```
function querySuccess_a2_2(tx2, results2) {

     inhalt = results2.rows.length;
     sObject ="";
     for( x=0; x<inhalt; x++){
         sObject += "<option value='"+results2.rows.item(x).typ_id+"'>"+results2.rows.item(x).typ_name+"</option>"; 

     }

     document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML ="<option value='99597'>Bitte Typ ausw&auml;hlen</option>"+sObject;
     aussuchen();

<form name="testform" action="" id="formIn_a2">         
<select name="States" id="sel" style="height:300px!important;">
<option default>Bitte Typ ausw&auml;hlen</option>
</select>
```

I would like to increase this to maybe 5-7 results but i can't figure out how to do this. I tried to increase the height of my div, or increase the high of the select i have, but nothing changes the results.

Where can i find the option to increase my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the number of rows shown with the [`rows`](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/2-13-2/select#!opt-rows) option.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this one by myself by editing the mobiscroll.js

There are two classes:

`dww` (which is the container high)
`dwwwol` (which is the position of the lines which show what you selected)

Just replace the two classes with variables and set the width you want at the top of your .js. Do not use `%` for dww, this will not work.